# randomly output quiz questions from xml file using array

Tags: android

This is my code for questions, my problem is that i cannot create a code to randomly output a question from xml without any duplication,
Here's my code:

```
public class QuizFunActivity extends Activity{
    Intent menu = null;
    BufferedReader bReader = null;
    static JSONArray quesList = null;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3*1000);
                    finish();
                    loadQuestions();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizFunActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
                    QuizFunActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                } 
            }
        };
        thread.start();

     }

    private void loadQuestions() throws Exception {
        try {
        InputStream questions = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questions));
        StringBuilder quesString = new StringBuilder();
        String aJsonLine = null;
        while ((aJsonLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            quesString.append(aJsonLine);
        }
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), quesString.toString());
        JSONObject quesObj = new JSONObject(quesString.toString());
        quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                "Num Questions " + quesList.length());
        } catch (Exception e){

        } finally {
            try {
                bReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
            }

        }


    }

    public static JSONArray getQuesList() {
        return quesList;
    }

}
```

can you give me a sample of which part on my code should i create a code for random output?
thanks for the help!

you may take a look with this activity,

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    EditText question = null;
    RadioButton answer1 = null;
    RadioButton answer2 = null;
    RadioButton answer3 = null;
    RadioButton answer4 = null;
    RadioGroup answers = null;
    Button finish = null;
    int selectedAnswer = -1;
    int quesIndex = 0;
    int numEvents = 0;
    int selected[] = null;
    int correctAns[] = null;
    boolean review =false;
    Button prev, next = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);

        TableLayout quizLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.quizLayout);
        quizLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);

        try {
            question = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question1);
            answer1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a0);
            answer2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a1);
            answer3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a2);
            answer4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.a3);
            answers = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answers);
            RadioGroup questionLayout = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.answers);
            Button finish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finish);
            finish.setOnClickListener(finishListener);

            prev = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Prev);
            prev.setOnClickListener(prevListener);
            next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next);
            next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);


            selected = new int[QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()];
            java.util.Arrays.fill(selected, -1);
            correctAns = new int[QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()];
            java.util.Arrays.fill(correctAns, -1);


            this.showQuestion(0,review);

            quizLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
        } 

    }


    private void showQuestion(int qIndex,boolean review) {
        try {
            JSONObject aQues = QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().getJSONObject(qIndex);
            String quesValue = aQues.getString("Question");
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == -1) {
                String correctAnsStr = aQues.getString("CorrectAnswer");
                correctAns[qIndex] = Integer.parseInt(correctAnsStr);
            }

            question.setText(quesValue.toCharArray(), 0, quesValue.length());
            answers.check(-1);
            answer1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            answer2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            answer3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            answer4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            JSONArray ansList = aQues.getJSONArray("Answers");
            String aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(0).getString("Answer");
            answer1.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(1).getString("Answer");
            answer2.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(2).getString("Answer");
            answer3.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(3).getString("Answer");
            answer4.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
            Log.d("",selected[qIndex]+"");
            if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                answers.check(R.id.a0);
            if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                answers.check(R.id.a1);
            if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                answers.check(R.id.a2);
            if (selected[qIndex] == 3)
                answers.check(R.id.a3);

            setScoreTitle();
            if (quesIndex == (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()-1)) 
                next.setEnabled(false);

            if (quesIndex == 0)
                prev.setEnabled(false);

            if (quesIndex > 0)
                prev.setEnabled(true);

            if (quesIndex < (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()-1))
                next.setEnabled(true);


            if (review) {
                Log.d("review",selected[qIndex]+""+correctAns[qIndex]);;    
                if (selected[qIndex] != correctAns[qIndex]) {
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                        answer1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                        answer2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                        answer3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    if (selected[qIndex] == 3)
                        answer4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 0)
                    answer1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 1)
                    answer2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 2)
                    answer3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                if (correctAns[qIndex] == 3)
                    answer4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
        }
    }


    private OnClickListener finishListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAnswer();
            //Calculate Score
            int score = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<correctAns.length; i++){
                if ((correctAns[i] != -1) && (correctAns[i] == selected[i]))
                    score++;
            }
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Score");
            alertDialog.setMessage((score) +" out of " + (QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length()));

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Retake", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    review = false;
                    quesIndex=0;
                    QuestionActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
                }
            });

            /* alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Review", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    review = true;
                    quesIndex=0;
                    QuestionActivity.this.showQuestion(0, review);
                }
            }); */

            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,"Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    review = false;
                        Intent instructionsIntent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,MainBookActivity.class);
                        startActivity(instructionsIntent);
                        finish();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();

        }
    };

    private void setAnswer() {
        if (answer1.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 0;
        if (answer2.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 1;
        if (answer3.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 2;
        if (answer4.isChecked())
            selected[quesIndex] = 3;

        Log.d("",Arrays.toString(selected));
        Log.d("",Arrays.toString(correctAns));

    }

    private OnClickListener nextListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAnswer();
            quesIndex++;
            if (quesIndex >= QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length())
                quesIndex = QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length() - 1;

            showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener prevListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAnswer();
            quesIndex--;
            if (quesIndex < 0)
                quesIndex = 0;

            showQuestion(quesIndex,review);
        }
    };

    private void setScoreTitle() {
        this.setTitle("SciQuiz3     " + (quesIndex+1)+ "/" + QuizFunActivity.getQuesList().length());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're gonna have to be a lot more specific and post a lot less unrelated code. Why can't you simply remove a question from the array, once it has been randomly picked once?

Comment: im sorry i did not get,

Comment: @Jerome stefan wants to say make ur question more clear and post only relevant code here.